# update value in javascript variable from input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below Javascript and HTML form code:

The problem is, when I enter the numeric value in the field and press the submit button, it doesn't send the value to the quantity variable. If i just refresh the page after entering the value, then it works. How do I get the value for quantity variable by clicking on submit button?

```js
var button = document.getElementById("theButton")
var send = button.form.valueId.value;
var quantiy = send;
var costPerItem = 10;
var amount = costPerItem * quantiy;
var tax = (amount * 3) / 100;
var discount = (amount * 2) / 100;
var total = amount - discount + tax;

document.write('Tax', " " + tax + "<br>");
document.write('Discount', " " + discount + "<br>");
document.write('total', " " + total);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="formValueId" name="valueId" />
  <input value="submit" type="button" id="theButton" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please do not use `document.write('text');`. Use `document.body.innerHTML += 'text';` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.write is used to Write some text directly to the HTML document. It is not editable later. So you will have to use div and update inner html instead

```js
function updateVal() {
var button = document.getElementById("theButton")
var send= button.form.valueId.value ;
var quantiy=send;
var costPerItem=10;
var amount= costPerItem*quantiy;
var tax= (amount*3)/100;
var discount=(amount*2)/100;
var total= amount-discount+tax;

document.getElementById("tax").innerHTML = "Tax " + tax;
document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML = "Discount " + discount;
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total " + total;
  
  }

updateVal();
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="formValueId" name="valueId"/>
<input  value="submit" type="button" onclick="updateVal()" id="theButton"/>
</form>

<div id="tax">Tax: 0</div>
<div id="discount">Discount: 0</div>
<div id="total">total: 0</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much i will try above code actually am new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a name to your form and change your button (`input[type="button"]`) into a submit button (`input[type="submit"]`), you can listen for the `onSubmit` event.

Also, by wrapping your text in spans, you can control the width and spacing of your output.

```js
document.forms["myForm"].onsubmit = function() {
  var quantity = this.valueId.value;
  var costPerItem = 10;
  var amount = costPerItem * quantity;
  var tax = (amount * 3) / 100;
  var discount = (amount * 2) / 100;
  var total = amount - discount + tax;

  var output = document.getElementById('output');

  write(output, ''); // Clear previous text.
  writeValue(output, 'Tax', tax);
  writeValue(output, 'Discount', discount);
  writeValue(output, 'Total', total);
}

function writeValue(el, label, amount) {
  writeLine(el, el.innerHTML,
    '<span class="lbl">' + label + ':</span>',
    '<span class="val">' + amount.toFixed(2) + '</span>');
}

function write(el, value) {
  el.innerHTML = [].slice.call(arguments, 1).join(' ');
}

function writeLine(el, value) {
  write.apply(undefined, [].slice.call(arguments).concat('<br />'));
}
```

```css
span.lbl {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
span.lbl:after {
  content: '$';
  position: absolute;
  left: 84px;
}
span.val {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 56px;
  text-align: right;
}
div#output {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="formValueId" name="valueId" value="42" />
  <input type="submit" id="theButton" value="submit" />
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```